# DSL to implement business rules for REST service routing and processing

Tags: scala, groovy, jax-rs, dsl, parser-combinators

I am hoping that `Combinator parsers`, (http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2008/04/external-dsls-made-easy-with-scala.html), will work for a design to process the routing rules for a REST service that is implemented with `Scalatra`,(http://tutorialbin.com/tutorials/80408/infoq-scalatra-a-sinatra-like-web-framework-for-scala).

This REST service is to serve as a proxy so external applications can get access to services within the firewall, as it will have additional layers of security that can be customized for the business requirements of each REST service.

So, if a person wants to access their class schedule there will be less security than if you want to look at the transcript of someone.

I would like the rules for where to go to actually get the information, and how to return it, as well as what security is needed, in a DSL.

But, the first problem is how to dynamically change the routing rules for the REST service based on a DSL, as I am trying to create a framework that doesn't require a great deal of recompiling to add new rules, but just write the appropriate scripts and just let it be processed.

So, can a DSL be implemented using the Combinator Parser, in Scala, that will allow JAX-RS (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) to have dynamically changed routing?

**UPDATE:**

I haven't designed the language yet, but this is what I am trying to do:

```
route /transcript using action GET to   
http://inside.com/transcript/{firstparam}/2011/{secondparam} 
return json encrypt with public key from /mnt/publickey.txt

for /education_cost using action GET combine http://combine.com/SOAP/costeducate with 
http://combine.com/education_benefit/2010 with 
http://combine.com/education_benefit/2011 return html
```

These are two possible ideas where rules for a request for a transcript is sent to a different site, such as within a firewall, and the data is encrypted and returned.

The second would be more complicated in that the results of a SOAP and two REST requests will be combined, and there would need to be additional commands on how this is combined, but the idea is to put all of this in files that can be parsed on the fly.

If I used Groovy then some new classes could be generated for the routing, which would remove some performance hits, but I think using Scala would be the best bet, even if I took a performance hit.

My hope is to make a framework that is more maintainable so new routing rules can be written by people that don't know any OOP or functional languages, but the specifications could be written using `Specs` (http://code.google.com/p/specs/) so that the functional side could be certain that their requirements are tested on a regular basis.

**UPDATE 2:**

When I start working on a design I may intuitively understand some options, but not know why.  Today I realized that the reason that Groovy may be a better fix for this is that I could then generate the classes for routing, using the metaprogramming (http://www.justinspradlin.com/programming/groovy-metaprogramming-adding-behavior-dynamically/), then I would be able to use Scala or Groovy to dynamically use the routing that was generated.  I am not certain how to get Scala to generate the classes if they don't already exist.

In Groovy, as well as some other languages, as shown here (http://langexplr.blogspot.com/2008/02/handling-call-to-missing-method-in.html) if a method is missing you can dynamically generate the method and it will henceforth exist, so it will be missing one time.

It almost seems that I should be mixing Groovy with Java to make this work, but then the result may be that some of the code is in Scala and some in Java, for the routing of REST services.

Comment: You don't need to generate classes: simple functions will do.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral - As my question states, if someone wants to create an /transcript or /education_cost endpoint I don't want them to have to go in and recompile the server code, but to write a script, and have it handled "magically".  So how would a simple function put in the code for the routing of the endpoint.  That is my struggle, how to do this purely within Scala, as I think I can do it by mixing Scala and Groovy, but now it gets much more complicated.

Comment: I'm saying it can be done with simple functions. With a parser you get a function that converts the DSL into an AST. You can then convert this into something a `Plan` (from Unfiltered), which is just a wrapper over a function that converts a request into a response. None of it requires defining new classes.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral - Thank you, I will watch the video.

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the question in two parts:

> can a DSL be implemented using the Combinator Parser

Yes. There are things that cannot be implemented using a combinator parser, or even other kinds of parser. For instance, Perl itself cannot be parsed (it must be evaluated). And combinator parsers are also not particularly good for complex languages (such as Scala -- its compiler is not based on combinator parsers), or if you demand top performance (such as the compilers used to compile hundreds of thousands of lines of code).

If, however, you plan to go to such extremes, choosing the parser is not going to be your main problem. For DSLs of average complexity, they'll do just fine.

> that will allow JAX-RS to have dynamically changed routing

Well, I don't know JAX-RS, but if dynamically changed routing can be done with it, then combinators parsers will be able to provide whatever input is needed.

**EDIT**

Seeing your example, I think parser combinators are certainly enough. From their results, I expect you could dynamically create BlueEyes binders -- I haven't used BlueEyes, so I'm not sure how dynamic they are.

Another alternative would be go with Lift. Lift's binders are partial functions, and they can be combined in all the usual ways -- `f1 orElse f2`, `f1 andThen f2`, etc. I didn't suggest it at first because it is most often used with sessions, but it has a RESTful model which, I *think*, is stateless.

I don't know Scalatra, so I don't know if it would be adaptable to this or not.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to write a DSL with comparators, but then I got stuck, in design, on the fact that I could have one REST service and change based on the first parameter, but I wonder if I am going down the wrong path.  It may be that this would be easier to implement with Groovy than Scala, for example.

Comment: @James Have you looked at [Unfiltered](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Unfiltered.html) or [BlueEyes](https://github.com/jdegoes/blueeyes)? If the problem is just decoding the REST path, they do that very well. (PS: Unfiltered and BlueEyes above are links)

Comment: The problem isn't just with decoding, as I don't want to have created the endpoint, I would like it to be created dynamically, based on what is in the control script, as I explained in more detail today, but these look interesting, so thank you.

Comment: My problem with Lift is that it is much heavier than what I need, as I am not doing templates, just REST service endpoints.  I have kept BlueEyes open in a tab, to look at more closely tomorrow, as I think that may have some promise, but I need to experiment and see.

Comment: @James [Here's](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/lightning-talks-talk-2-at-scalax) a webcast about Unfiltered -- just 10 minutes + 5 of questions. I think you should take a look at it. I didn't suggest Lift at first because I too think it's too heavy, but I wasn't familiar enough with the alternatives to categorically state they could do the function thingy. With that video from Unfiltered, I now know _it_ can do it for sure.